# treat CSV document to retrieve data separately obtained with file_picker package in flutter web

Tags: flutter, filepicker.io

First I apologize for the English.
I'm trying to format the data from a csv file obtained with the file_picker package in which I'm trying to separate the information to insert the information into a database.

```
Future<String> pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      dialogTitle: 'Selecione o arquivo',
      allowMultiple: true,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['csv'],
    );

    if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
      var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
      var formater = String.fromCharCodes(fileBytes!);

      //print(formater);

      List<String> listCsv = formater.split(";");

      String nome = '';
      String telefone = '';
      String email = '';
      String cpf = '';

      for (int i = 0; i < listCsv.length; i += 4) {
        nome = listCsv[i];
        telefone = listCsv[i + 1];
        email = listCsv[i + 2];
        cpf = listCsv[i + 3];

        print(RegistersModel(name: nome, phone: telefone, cpf: cpf, email: email));
      }

      //final path = result.files.single.path;
      //print(path);

      return csv = formater;
    } else {
      return 'O documento não foi retornado';
    }
  }
```

Could someone tell me how I can do this because that way the last section with line information ends up joining the first field of the next line.

```
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: Hadila, email: hadila.teste@gmail.com, phone: (16)96584-3216, cpf: 154.368.954-94
Ana, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: (16)96584-3215, email: 154.368.954-93
Amanda, phone: ana.teste@gmail.com, cpf: (16)96584-3214, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: amanda.teste@gmail.com, email: (16)96584-3213, phone: 154.368.954-92
Bruno, cpf: bruno.teste@gmail.com, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: 154.368.954-91
Vanesa, email: vanessa.teste@gmail.com, phone: (16)96584-3212, cpf: 154.368.954-90
Jonas, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: (16)96584-3211, email: 154.368.954-89
Murilo, phone: jonas.teste@gmail.com, cpf: (16)96584-3210, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: murilo.teste@gmail.com, email: (16)96584-3209, phone: 154.368.954-88
Daniel, cpf: daniel.teste@gmail.com, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: 154.368.954-87
Bianca, email: bianca.teste@gmail.com, phone: (16)96584-3208, cpf: 154.368.954-86
Pamela, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: (16)96584-3207, email: 154.368.954-85
Roberto, phone: pamela.teste@gmail.com, cpf: (16)96584-3206, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: roberto.teste@gmail.com, email: (16)96584-3205, phone: 154.368.954-84
Fabricio, cpf: vfabricio.teste@gmail.com, idUser: null)
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: 154.368.954-83
Claudia, email: claudia.teste@gmail.com, phone: (16)96584-3204, cpf: 154.368.954-82
Pablo, idUser: null)
Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 43: 43
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at [dartx._get] (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:17547:21)
    at general_registers_controller.GeneralRegistersController.new.pickFile (http://localhost:55593/packages/project_002_italian_citizenship/src/controllers/general_registers_controller.dart.lib.js:169:33)
    at pickFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:55593/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

And to make matters worse I'm getting an error that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: please add some lines from your csv file

Comment: that's a few lines
Hadila;(16)96584-3216;hadila.teste@gmail.com;154.368.954-94
Ana;(16)96584-3215;ana.teste@gmail.com;154.368.954-93
Amanda;(16)96584-3214;amanda.teste@gmail.com;154.368.954-92
Bruno;(16)96584-3213;bruno.teste@gmail.com;154.368.954-91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first split the contacts bye whitespaces then split each contact bye semicolon

```
final formater = String.fromCharCodes(fileBytes!);
final contacts = formater.split('\r'); // Carriage Return ascii code 13
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length - 1; i++) {
    final contactData = contacts[i].split(';');
    print(RegistersModel(
        name: contactData[0],
        phone: contactData[1],
        email: contactData[2],
        cpf: contactData[3],
    ));
}
```

**NOTE: this will only work if all the CSVs loaded have this specific format**

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, but can I ask you a question, you said that this only works if it has the specific format, is there any other way to recover the file so that it doesn't require it?

Comment: Idk, just make sure when your store a CSV file do it like this order: name;phone;email;cpf if your file have this format the above method should work no problem

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me this was the return:
GeneralRegistersModel (id: null, name: Hadila, email: hadila.teste@gmail.com, phone: (16)96584-3216, CPF: 154.368.954-94
Ana, idUser: null)

Comment: Ana remains united with the numbers

Comment: weird, there is a white-space between the number and the name, right? or is it a newline char?

Comment: I'm not sure but as I'm getting the data from the file I think it's a new line character

Comment: then try formater.split('\n') instead of formater.split(' ')

Comment: I tried but it throws an error Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1

Comment: I tried it myself using a file.csv, it's working

Comment: How strange in mine will not

Comment: can you send your file.csv or upload it somehow?

Comment: I don't know how I can send you the file

Comment: you can upload it to any website and share the link here

Comment: See if you can access https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W0HJFI9cXXKQ1sq9JblCuAfs229FSvJf/view?usp=share_link

Comment: looks like your file is using Carriage Return, I updated the answer, it worked for me using your file.csv for more info see: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/863.cfm